# How to mass email with Laravel & Mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

My mission is to mass emails the users of my site.

I want to take the emails of all the users of my site, and send them a message, aka bulk email.

I'm using mailgun service at the moment to send confirmation emails when a user signs up to my site. below is an example of some of the code I'm using.

I want to know if I could use a similar code to send bulk email.

```
public function sendEmail($sub)
{
    $user = $this;
    Mail::send('mail.confirm',['user' => $user, $sub => $sub], function($mail) use ($user,$sub) {
     $mail->from('website@gmail.com', 'Website');
     $mail->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject($sub . ' Confirm Website Email');
    });
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: I dont know how the PHP sdk works, but Mailgun itself has the concept of list up to 2.5 million recipients. You need to add them first then sending to the list alias will send a copy to all recipients.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Queues for this stuffs.

Make a queue file like below:

```
class SendEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    public  $data , $email;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data,$email)
    {
        $this->data=$data;
        $this->email=$email;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        Mail::send('mail.confirm', [
                    'title' => $this->data['body'] ,
                    'body' => $this->data['body'],
                    ,
                ], function ($message) {
                    $message->from('no-reply@testmail.com', 'Test Notification');
                    $message->to($this->email)->subject($this->data['subject']));
                }
                );


    }

}
```

Call it from the controller:

```
use App\Jobs\SendEmail;
class EmailController extends Controller {

    public function send() {
        $data = array
            (
            'title' => 'title',
            'body' => 'body',
            'subject' => 'subject'
        );

        $emails=array("email1@email.com","email2@email.com")
        foreach($emails as $val){
            $this->dispatch(new SendEmail($data, $val));
        }


}
```

Please check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues
and https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-laravel-queues-are-awesome